# Can't close Drawe in OnClickListener in my Adapter

Tags: android

I can't close Drawer in OnClickListener in my Adapter
Here is OnClickListener

```
    private View.OnClickListener Click=new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            drlay.closeDrawers(); // ERROR !!!
            switch(getPosition())
            {
                case 1:
                    i.setComponent(new ComponentName(contxt,Top.class));
                    i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                    break;}
```

Here is the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myapplication.MyAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:77)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter cannot find your drawer layout.

Such things shouldn't be handled in the adapter though try moving the listener to your activity hosting the drawer and instead use setOnItemClickListener on the list view.